# Set addressDictionary with kABPersonAddress Properties

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm getting errors when trying to set `addressDictionary` using kABPerson properties. Am I setting it incorrectly in swift?

Error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'kABPersonAddress...'
```

This is the code:

```
@IBAction func mapButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.759212, -73.984632)
    let addressDict =
    [kABPersonAddressStreet as NSString: "5 main st",
        kABPersonAddressCityKey: "New York",
        kABPersonAddressStateKey: "NY",
        kABPersonAddressZIPKey: "10001"]

    let p = MKPlacemark(coordinate:coords, addressDictionary:addressDict)
    let mi = MKMapItem(placemark: p)
    mi.name = restaurantName // label to appear in Maps app
    //let span = NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan:self.map.region.span)
    let opts = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey: MKMapType.Standard.rawValue,
        //MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: span
    ]
    mi.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(opts)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key name is `kABPersonAddressStreetKey` not `kABPersonAddressStreet`, also if you explicitly set the dictionary type you don't need to cast the keys:

```
let addressDict: [String: String] = [
    kABPersonAddressStreetKey: "5 main st",
    kABPersonAddressCityKey: "New York",
    kABPersonAddressStateKey: "NY",
    kABPersonAddressZIPKey: "10001"
]
```

Comment: Add "import AddressBook" on top of the file